# SVN switch to a different branch, allowing me to merge/commit later

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn, subclipse

Seems like I should be able to do this using Subclipse or Tortoise.

I began work on a feature in a branch and the scope of that feature grew, so I am not checking in to keep that branch stable.
I want a place to check in, so I've branched the original branch, and I'd like to point my copy to that branch.

Using SVN switch, it seems I must resolve conflicts as part of the process, but I am not prepared to do that. I just want my workspace to now point to the copy of the branch it was pointing to before, allowing me to merge and update on my own time.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch has to do an update.  I do not think your issue is with switch, it is probably with the branch you created.  Suppose your working copy is updated to r100 of your repository and you start making changes locally.  Now you decide to create your branch and you create it based on the repository HEAD which is not at r150.  Then yeah, you might have some problems because the branch was not really created from the same source as your working copy.

If you want to optimize around making it easy to stash your change, then the best thing will be to create your branch from the working copy. This is one of the options in the wizard when you select your project and choose Team > Create Branch/Tag...

Working copies can be in crazy mixed-revision states and that is what the branch will be created from.  So it can be a little more difficult later when you want to go back to your change and want to merge it back to trunk or get the branch caught up with trunk.

If you have a rough idea what revision your working copy is up to, then the middle-ground approach would be to create the branch against the repository revision.  Then the branch is clean and you minimize the likelihood of conflicts when you update the working copy with the switch.

Comment: I think you understand my problem but I'm not sure I understand your solution. I think my problem is I don't fully understand the purpose of switch. Basically, my working copy is of trunk, but with trunk frozen, I need to commit my code somewhere (a branch of the current trunk). I want to continue working, committing/resolving conflicts on my schedule I just want my working copy to be from this branch of trunk, not trunk. 
Switch seems to require you to sync up the working copy and the new repo location as part of it's process, which I don't need to do right now.

Comment: I understand your problem, what you want does not exist.  Switch updates your working copy to point at a new branch, and that requires doing an update.  The techniques I gave you were to ensure as best you can that the branch was identical to your working copy, making the update a no-op or close to it.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the guidelines and have successfully switched over. I resolved all conflicts prior to branching and switching. Any advice on when I must merge this branch back into it's original line? Thanks.

Comment: Now that the code is on a branch, you normally finish the work there.  So you can periodically "sync" branch with trunk by doing a full merge to your branch.  When you are all done, just have an updated working copy from trunk and merge the branch back into it ... review and commit.

Comment: Thanks, this was my next area of confusion and sync merge was the term I was looking for. I envisioned merging trunk to my feature branch and wondered how conflicts would be handled but now I see how my working copy plays its part as the 'proving ground' for the merge. 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand what you want to do. In any case, you'd have to talk to your colleagues about those conflicts before resolving them.

But if you want to postpone the conflict resolution and begin working on the new branch, just checkout a new working copy of the new branch. Leave your existing working copy with uncommitted changes (don't remove it!) and use the new clean working copy.

Comment: I have a modified working copy of a branch, I want to create a temporary branch of that branch, point my current working copy towards it, and continue working WITHOUT having to merge/update my current changes.
Switch does this, except it does a dumb text merge to all my files with conflicts, which is almost all of them. I just want to change where my copy points to and keep working on it, eventually merging back in but not right this second the way SVN wants me to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you have the original branch (Branch 1) and a branch that you have created from this branched code (Branch 2). Instead of switching from Branch 1 to Branch 2, I would checkout Branch 2, copy my changes made in Branch 1 (resolving any conflicts) and commit to Branch 2. I have found that using SVN switch between branched code bases is not as graceful as it should be, and sometimes it is better to just copy/paste code changes.

Comment: Thanks, it's looking like this is my only option. I was really hoping I could postpone resolving the conflicts but it looks like switch is as powerful as it I thought.